# Disable F1-F12 Key in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want disable F1 to F12 key in query.

There are many threads available on Stack Overflow about  disable but there is not which work for all from F1 to F12. How to I make disable button from F1 to f2 in jQuery.

Comment: Show the approach that you going to try and didn't work for you.

Comment: Simple answer: don't even bother.

Comment: Given your latest question about building a phishing website (and the -5 it acquired) I would say you're very close to a question ban. I suggest you make more of an effort with your questions (and try to steer away from fraudulent enterprises).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this.

1) use a function like this

```
function DisableKeys() {
    var ar = new Array(122 , 123);
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false; 
       }
        return true;
    });
}
```

2) example 2

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(e.which === 122){
    return false;
if(e.which === 123){
    return false;
}
```

});

3) example 3

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
// keycode for F11 function
if (e.keyCode === 122) {
  return false;
}
// keycode for F12 function
if (e.keyCode === 123) {
// try to cancel the backspace
  return false;
}
};
```

Comment: it will only disable F11 and F12
ASCII code of function keys is given in the link below. change the ASCII values to disable other keys. 
https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/ascii-code-for-functions-keys-f1-f12-and-tab-key.277457/